# Very slow alter table (even without rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I've a problem with my Mysql setup: each alter table I make takes about 5 minutes to complete, even if the table is completely empty.

Sometimes the query even fails due to a timeout (Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE ...).

Furthermore, the table is in a test database, so there are no other queries going on concurrently.

I use Mysql 5.7 on a 12 CPUs machine, so I don't think that hardware is the problem.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

thanks for your time

**EDIT:**
When running `show full processlist`

```
Altering table  ALTER TABLE ...
Waiting for table metadata lock ALTER TABLE ...
```

PS: this behaviour happens on any table, and with every ALTER TABLE statement

**EDIT:** 
The issue was solved in Mysql 5.7.8

Comment: Only `ALTER TABLE` queries are slow or some other queries too?

Comment: All the other queries are fast. Once it managed 40k insert/sec ;)

Comment: What is the ALTER you're trying to do?  What is the table you're trying to do it on?

Comment: Run a `show full processlist` from another client and see whats the state of your alter statement

Comment: I've updated my question to include additional info

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that nothing else is using the table? Try creating a test table and alter that one.

Comment: Looks to me it's waiting for a table-level lock before doing the actual altering. That makes sense. So your problem is that something else is locking the table before you try to alter it.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. I'm on a test database, and I'm altering a test table (the issue happens on all the tables in my Mysql instance).

Comment: more info needed ! os ? my.cnf ? do you use good values for index, innodb ? Special notice if you have a software raid on your system

Answer (score 0):

Try your query here.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html

If Anything bad in query, you will find it.

Else

A full dump and reload is more faster than alter.

i.e.

```
- Create a new table (using the structure of the current table) with the new column(s) included.

- execute a INSERT INTO new_table SELECT (column1,..columnN) FROM current_table;

- rename the current table

- rename the new table using the name of the current table.
```